# How can I display a user profile using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django and I am currently trying to build a website that allows users to sign in and view other users profiles. So far I have managed to let users sign in but I can't work out how to view other peoples profiles.

Each profile uses the users username to create a url for their profile. Currently if I sign in as one user and change the URL to another users profile URL, it still displays the current users profile. I want something similar to pinterest where any person whether they are signed in or not can view peoples profiles.

Any help would be appreciated!

View

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from howdidu.forms import UserProfileForm
from howdidu.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def index(request):
    context_dict = {'boldmessage': "I am bold font from the context"}
    return render(request, 'howdidu/index.html', context_dict)

#user profile form
@login_required
def register_profile(request):
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return index(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'howdidu/register_profile.html', {'form': form})

#profile page using user name as url
@login_required
def profile_page(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return render(request, 'howdidu/profile.html', {'profile_user': user})
```

project url

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):  #redirects to home page after registration
    def get_success_url(self,request, user):
        return '/register_profile'

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'howdidu_project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('howdidu.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'), #redirects to home page after registration
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/', include('howdidu.urls')), #do i need this?
)

# media
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)',
        'serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

app url

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from howdidu import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^register_profile/$', views.register_profile, name='register_profile'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile_page, name='user_profile'),
        )
```

template

```
{% extends 'howdidu/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ user.username }}{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1>{{ user.username }} welcome to your profile page</h1>
        <img src="{{ user.userprofile.profile_picture.url }}" width = "150" height = "150"  />
        <h2>{{ user.userprofile.first_name }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ user.userprofile.second_name }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ user.userprofile.user_country }}</h2>
        {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Register urls of your app in the configuration folder `project_name/urls.py` :
   E.g :

```python
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/', include('<app_name>.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

1. Add a new route in your `<app_name>/urls.py`. 
   E.g :

from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'profile/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', views.get_user_profile),
]
```

2. Add a view in `<app_name>/views.py` that take `username` (username of the user) to retrieve its information and send them into a template
   E.g :

```python
from django.shortcuts import render

def get_user_profile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, '<app_name>/user_profile.html', {"user":user})
```

3. Create a template file in `<app_name>/templates/<app_name>/user_profile.html`to display `user`  object :

```python
{{ user.username }} 
{{ user.email }}
{{ user.first_name }} 
{{ user.last_name }}
```

Replace `<app_name>` by the name of your app and it should be good.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My code is near exact to that apart from different names here and there. I still seem to have the same issue. For example if my website was www.example.com and my username is oliver. When I go to www.example.com/oliver I can go to my user profile ok when signed in. Whilst still signed in if I tried to go to another users profile like www.example.com/katie, I seem to still get the user profile of oliver. What would I need to do to ensure other users data stays on each url for each users profile? Would I need to change my view in some way?

Comment: in your view, you have to retrieve data of the username pass through the url `profile/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$`. Add your current view to your question please

Comment: I have just uploaded my code :-) hopefully it will make more sense now

Comment: Your code is good man, it should work. Add your template too, please

Comment: Just uploaded the template, its very basic at the moment!

Comment: You did a mistake in your template, you send a 'profile_user' variable that contains profile data but in your template you display 'user' variable instead of 'profile_user'. Use '{{ profile_user.username }}' and it should be good.

Comment: Thank you so so so much! That worked a treat! :-D